# Duplicate issue when using tags component as a menu item

Tags: sef, joomla-5.x

The problem is this. Created a menu item - list of tags. I will give an example for clarity. site/tags-menu-item, if you add for this menu item, for example, site/tags-menu-item/55/, a duplicate will be displayed, but a 404 error should be displayed.
You can check it on this site: https://recepty.mobi/paskhalnye-retsepty/kulichi

Can you tell me how to solve the problem? Joomla 5